# how to use git branch for new feature

Tags: git

I am working on new feature branch feature/b1 and pushed some changes to remote repo. To continue with more changes to the same feature/b1 how to proceed

1. Create new feature/b2  and push it to remote repo?
2. Stay in the same feature/b1 and make new changes and push feature/b1 again to the remote repo?
3. Do we have any merge conflicts if  we use the same feature/b1 branch

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Feature branches should be **self-contained**. That is to say, a 'feature' (unit of work) should be small enough by design that it does not require any sub-features. As such, you should never need to branch a feature branch from another feature branch.

If there is additional work to be done on the `b1` feature, you stay on the `b1` branch and make a secondary commit. If there are changes that are *not* part of the `b1` feature, you switch to a different feature branch.

Ideally, you would follow [Git Flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), and branch both `b1` and `b2` off of a `dev` or `develop` branch, then create a pull request back to `dev` / `develop` when you want to 'combine' the logic. It is at this point that there is the potential for merge conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So you do multiple commits staying in same b1 branch. When all work finished on b1.